# Cyclic references and DI

Tags: c#, wcf, ninject

I have a wcf project named Service1 that has an Interface IActions

```
public interface IActions
{
    int DoSomething(int param);
}

public class Service1 : IService1
{
    private IActions actions;

    public Service1(IActions actions)
    {
        this.actions = actions;
    }

    public MyAction(int p)
    {
        return this.actions.DoSomething(p);
    }

}
```

then I have other project that implements IActions interface, so it has a reference to Service1

```
public class SomeClass : IActions
{
    public int DoSomething(int param)
    {
        return param*param;
    }
}
```

Now I want to implement DI with ninject, and to do so I am doing this bindings

```
public class NinjectBindings : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<IActions>().To<SomeClass>();
        Bind<ServiceHost>().To<NinjectServiceHost>();
    }

}
```

this isnt possible because it introduces cyclic references.
What am i doing wrong?
I know i should have design flaws, but I appreciate that you may show them to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have a cyclic reference of your classes in your example. You just have cyclic assembly references. Introduce some contract assembly that contains the interfaces shared between them and you'll be fine.

Comment: that was my first thought, but shouldnt the interfaces be in the service assembly?

Comment: No, they shouldn't or else you'd be statically coupling the client to the service's assembly. So why remote in the first place?